# Error: $injector:unpr Unknown Provider when using filter

Tags: angularjs

I am very new to AngularJS and trying to learn.
I am stuck at a place and could not find anything.I am trying to do the pagination :

JS Code...

```
$scope.data = [];
$scope.currentPage = 0;
$scope.pageSize = 2;
$scope.q = '';

$scope.getData = function() {
  // needed for the pagination calc
  // https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/filter/filter
  return $filter('filter')($scope.data, $scope.q)

}

$scope.numberOfPages = function() {
  return Math.ceil($scope.getData().length / $scope.pageSize);
}

$scope.getJSONData = function(lst) {
$scope.data.push(lst);
}
// $scope.paginationPage();

}]);
app.filter('startFrom', function() {
      return function(input, start) {

        start = +start; //parse to int
        var result = input.slice(start);
        return result;
      }

        ......
```

I am getting the error Error: `Error: [$injector:unpr]`

M DOM looks like :

```
<tr ng-repeat="p in data | startFrom:currentPage*pageSize | 
             limitTo:pageSize">

  <td class="slds-cell-shrink" style="border:groove;">
    <label class="slds-checkbox testclass">
                                <input type="checkbox" ng-model='p.vlcSelected' ng-change='onSelectItem(control, p, $index, this)'/>

                                <span class="slds-checkbox--faux"></span>
                                <span class="slds-assistive-text">Select</span>
                            </label>
  </td>
```

Can anyone please help??

Comment: Can you show your controller definition?  My guess is you didn't inject `$filter`

Comment: Your filter is `'startFrom'`, but you use `'filter'` (which is a name of the filter)

Comment: @sh0ber ..can you help me how do i need to inject that?

Comment: `controller($scope, $filter)`

Comment: @sh0ber .. yes.. i have already done that

Comment: And what about @AlekseySolovey's comment?